# Posix RegEx for parsing email message - how to stop after first occurrence of boundary

Tags: regex, email-parsing

I am working on the parser of email message in MIME format. I am forced to use "posix regex" library written in C and I wonder of its behaviour.

Suppose we have following part of email message:

```
--------------010402010107070509040804
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-2
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

plain message

--------------010402010107070509040804
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

html message

--------------010402010107070509040804--
```

Now I need to get different types of message (plain and html). I used following pattern to get data between boundaries:

```
^((.|\\s)+?)--------------010402010107070509040804
```

This pattern works well in some RegEx libraries. For example, when I wrote the same regex process in javascript, I was able to get those two parts of message without any problem.

However, "posix regex" library returns me the whole message excluding "--" at the end. This is its result:

```
--------------010402010107070509040804
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-2
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

plain message

--------------010402010107070509040804
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

html message

--------------010402010107070509040804
```

Why it did not stop after finding first occurrence of boundary after plain message? Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried with Javascript and it did the same thing as POSIX, are you sure ?

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to write "?" regex symbol to the pattern. I edited my original contribution.

Comment: Do you really have two backslashes (`\\s`) in your regex?

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of using alternation, when `.` will match anything that `\s` will match? In other words, is there some reason you're not using `^(.+?)` at the beginning?

Comment: Symbol `.` does not match line breaks as far as I know (`\s` does). Here is the thing - originally I wrote that regex pattern in javascript and then I realized that javascript regex engine is not able to process huge amount of data. That is why I have decided to use native library (and to use posix regex) and to load it in javascript using ctypes.
Pattern `^(.+?)` returns no match in JS, however `^((.|\\s)+?)` and `^([\\s\\S]+?)` are fine. But only pattern `^((.|\\s)+?)` returns something in both engines - in JS it returns exactly what I need, in posix it returns the result written above.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX doesn't have greediness modifiers, there's a way to do it but it's ugly and long. To simplify, say the token was much shorter, like `--123`, you'd need this regex:

```
^(([^-]|-[^-]|--[^1]|--1[^2]|--12[^3])+)
```

That's already insanely long for something so simple. Basically you're telling the regex that you want a repetition of anything that isn't `-`, or a `-` **followed** by anything that isn't `-`, or `--` followed by anything that isn't `1`, and so on and so on.

I made a script to produce a regex from an input token and ran it with `--------------010402010107070509040804` and it gave me this:

```
^(([^-]|-[^-]|--[^-]|---[^-]|----[^-]|-----[^-]|------[^-]|-------[^-]|--------[^-]|---------[^-]|----------[^-]|-----------[^-]|------------[^-]|-------------[^-]|--------------[^0]|--------------0[^1]|--------------01[^0]|--------------010[^4]|--------------0104[^0]|--------------01040[^2]|--------------010402[^0]|--------------0104020[^1]|--------------01040201[^0]|--------------010402010[^1]|--------------0104020101[^0]|--------------01040201010[^7]|--------------010402010107[^0]|--------------0104020101070[^7]|--------------01040201010707[^0]|--------------010402010107070[^5]|--------------0104020101070705[^0]|--------------01040201010707050[^9]|--------------010402010107070509[^0]|--------------0104020101070705090[^4]|--------------01040201010707050904[^0]|--------------010402010107070509040[^8]|--------------0104020101070705090408[^0]|--------------01040201010707050904080[^4])+)
```

A beast but the best POSIX can do as far as I know :P